# Changing Height and Width of View programatically leads to unexpected behaviour in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, gradient

I was making a view rounded by using

```
dashboardView.layer.cornerRadius = dashboardView.frame.height/2
```

And it was working. Then I changed the height and width of my View with this method

```
dashboardView.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.width/2,y: 300,width: 200,height: 200)
```

Now when I try to make it round by using same method, it's not working. 
I was also adding a gradient layer on the view with this method

```
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let endingColorOFGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 133/255, green: 210/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    let startingColorOfGradient = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 50/255, green: 189/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dashboardView.layer.frame.width, height: dashboardView.layer.frame.height)
    gradient.colors = [startingColorOfGradient , endingColorOFGradient]
    self.dashboardView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex:0)
    // making gradient round
    gradient.cornerRadius = dashboardView.frame.height/2
```

And after changing the size of View gradient, the layer does become round but my View does not.

This is the View I created. Actually I want to change its size according to device. It should be small on iphone 5 and larger on iphone 6+
[image]

This is what I am getting
[image]
I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Can you show us what you have and what you expect? You might want to add `dashboardView.layer.masksToBounds = true` as well.

Comment: @BrandonShegaI have Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Autolayout constraints.

I was trying to change the size of view but Autolayout was putting it back. So I created outlet of my Height and Width constraint and changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

call `dashboardView.layer.cornerRadius = dashboardView.frame.height/2` again after setting gradient because you are changing frame so it's height should be different so your `dashboardView.frame.height/2` have different value.

and try to set `clipstobounds` to `true` for `dashboardView` if required.